# Is there a way to invoke a python subprocess within a python script and direct the return from the subprocess to a file opened by the script?

Tags: python

For many reasons merging the two routines isn't a viable option - lots of timing issues and sleep cycles will be at odds with each other. 
Routine 1 attaches to a device and opens a log file and populates it with some json data. 
Routine 2 attaches to a device and outputs json data.

Is there an approach that would enable routine 1 to invoke routine 2 but capture the data returned by routine two in the log file opened (and in use ) by routine 1?

Comment: You do it the same way you capture the output of any other subprocess that writes to standard output.

Comment: There's nothing special about the subprocess being another Python process.

Comment: have used subprocess but the documented subprocess.run(["./routine2.py"], capture_output=True) invokes but the output of routine 2 isn't returned. As well, it isn't entirely clear to me how to pass whatever is returned to f.write. Hints or even a 20,000 ft overview of the considerations would be appreciated. FWIW using but not married to v 3.6

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_output()`